# Wordpress nav rendering modification

Tags: wordpress, wp-nav-walker

Right now I have a menu which rendering like this

`wp_nav_menu(array(
    'menu'                  => 'header',
    'walker'  => new Header_menu_walker()
);`

It has 2 level and render in clasic way:

---

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Item 3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Item 4.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

Expected result:

```
<ul>
    <li data-id="1"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li data-id="2"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li data-id="3"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li data-id="4"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>

<ul data-parent-id="3" class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 3.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3.2</a></li>
</ul>
<ul data-parent-id="4"  class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 4.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4.2</a></li>
</ul>
```

I was trying to do it with Walker_Nav_Menu class but stack and have no idea how to solve it. Any help?

My Walker class:

```
class Header_menu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu  {
  var $sub_menus = [];

  function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output )
  {
      if ($depth > 0){
        return; 
      }
      return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
  }


  function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    if ($depth == 0){ 
      return;
    }else{
      $output .='<ul data-parent-id='.$args->parent_menu_id.'>';
    }

    return parent::start_lvl($output, $depth, $args );

  }

  function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    if ($depth == 0){
      $this->display_element($sub_menus, [], 0, 0);
      return;
    }else{
      $output .= '</ul>';
    }
    return parent::end_lvl($output, $depth, $args );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's the code for your walker?

Comment: I was trying to solve it with Walker class but, render only first level. So I haven`t it

Comment: Don't expect anyone to know how to help you then if you don't show us your code. A walker is a very complex thing, it's not just something can show you how to do. We need to see what you've tried, as part of the rules of asking questions.

Comment: ok. Got it. Updated.

Comment: And what is being outputted?

Comment: This probably isn’t trivial to achieve, because the walker creates the menu output recursively. // Why do you need the HTML structure like that? Perhaps there’s other ways to achieve the visual(?) effect you want.

Comment: Visit this page - http://115.outsourcer.in.ua/projects/. http://prntscr.com/c9dusw - click here. I get menu object and render it as I need. But for now I have a problem. How to hightlight active page. Some menu items it`s pages and some custom taxonomies. I thought it`ll be easier to do it with walker